# Extract and store parts of string's text on jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this string, containing 2 warnings and 3 errors, each warning/error is determined by it's start `warning:` or `error:`, and its ending, `_` symbol:

```
var data="warning:No data found_error:There's no data to display_error:Too many connections_warning:Test not passed:please check spelling_error:Connection lost";
```

How can I make jQuery extract each error and warning separately? On a structure like this:

```
if (data.indexOf("warning:") >= 0){
   var warnings.="<p class='warning'>"+EACHWARNINGHERE+"</p>";}
```

So that variable warnings would store this values:

```
var warnings="
<p class='warning'>No data found</p>
<p class='warning'>Test not passed:please check spelling</p>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use split:

```
var data="warning:No data found_error:There's no data to display_error:Too many connections_warning:Test not passed:please check spelling_error:Connection lost";
var a = data.split('warning:');//first split by `warning:`
var c = [];
var warnings = '';
for(var i in a){
    var b = a[i].split('error:');//now every part split again but by `error:`
    if(b[0]){
        warnings += "<p class='warning'>"+b[0].replace(/_$/,'')+"</p>";
    }
}
```

Now `warnings` is:

```
<p class='warning'>No data found</p>
<p class='warning'>Test not passed:please check spelling</p>
```

Comment: Thank you n-dru. Why do you set .split('warning') for variable a, and .split('error:') for variable b? I need to understand what it does as I must extract separately every error and warning. Thank you.

Comment: Seen comments. I'll try to adapt the code to my final need.Very grateful, i'll tick in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

split on '_' and then check if the sentences start with 'warning:' or 'error:'

```
var sentences = data.split('_')
for (var i=0; i<sentences.length; i++) {
    ver sentence = sentences[i];
    var sentenceType = data.slice(0,data.indexOf(':'));
    var sentenceText = sentence.slice(data.indexOf(':')+1);
    if (sentenceType == 'warning') {
       // add warning element with sentenceText
    }
    else {
       // add error element
    }
}
```